# Visual Studio 2013 C# Add all images from imagelist to listview

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, image-loading, imagelist

Currently I have zero code to show and display because I am new to using Visual Studio, Let me first explain what result I am trying to get so that you can better understand what I am trying to do. I will be making my first attempt at coding a program in C# using a great deal of images.

I added about 1300 images to imageList1 and I am trying to get all of these images to display vertically with their own picturbox or in a listview on form load so sooner or later making it so these images can be dragged and dropped into another window which will output code. I need these images to load from the program itself and not a local directory. Not sure if imageList is the best way to go for this or not.

I have googled and found nothing on what I am trying to do. Right now all I need help with is getting the images in imagelist to even display. I have googled for 2 days and found nothing on what I am looking to do, may be due to keywords entered but I found nothing.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to loop through the imageList and dynamically create 130 picturebox controls and set those controls to the images contained in the imaglist?

Comment: Yes I believe that is correct. I want to be able to pull all the images from the imagelist and display all of them as an image on the form. I am not sure if using listview is the best way or making pictureboxs for each though. Like I said I am very new to Visual Studios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this (not sure of positioning picture boxes though):

```
    PictureBox pb = default(PictureBox);
        int x = 0, y = 3000;
        foreach (Image img in imglist1.Images)
        {
            pb = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            pb.Image = img;
            pb.Width = 1450;
            pb.Height = 1450;
            //x += 1000;
            y -= 1000;
            pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x,y);

            //pb.Location.X = x;
            //pb.Location.Y = y;
            this.Controls.Add(pb);
        }
```

Comment: This works great, How can I add this to another control so for instance I can have some sort of scroll bar so I can see every image. All of the images are going off the form and no current way to scroll through them.

Comment: you can add it to any control the following way: ControlName.Controls.Add(pb)

Comment: I tried that already but its does not allow the images to scroll as if its in a list and it makes them static unable to move at all.